# Will adding site search microdata get Google to show a site search field when users search for your brand?

Tags: seo, google-search, search, sitelinks, site-search

For some reason, a search for our company name (“[hometalk](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=hometalk)”) does not produce the search box in the results (even though we do have sitelinks).

We are adding schema markup as outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/richsnippets/sitelinkssearch), but we're not sure about:

Will adding the code make the search bar appear (or at least increase the chances), or is it only going to change the functionality of the search box (to on-site search) for results that are already showing a search bar?

Comment: It will ask Google to show **Sitelinks Search Box** for your site. I think you have not implemented step 2. Implement it and wait for Google to detect the change.

Answer (score 2):

I checked your homepage source code to see if the 2nd step (putting the schema.org markup on your homepage) has been followed. That snippet is not yet implemented. Doing so will make your site an eligible candidate for displaying the site search bar on Google search results.